# I cannot publish from a different VS2012 - Error pointing to Service Runtime not being present?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

I have just moved my application to a different computer. The first computer was running VS2012 and the second also VS2012. However on the second computer when I try to deploy I receive the following message:

```
6:51:20 PM - Warning: There are package validation warnings.
6:51:20 PM - Preparing deployment for X - 12/12/2012 6:47:41 PM with Subscription ID 'X' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
6:51:20 PM - Connecting...
6:51:22 PM - Verifying storage account 'dX'...
6:51:24 PM - Uploading Package...
6:58:57 PM - Updating...
7:02:46 PM - Role instances recycled for a certain amount of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent role instances from running. The most likely reason for this is that your code throws an unhandled exception. Please consider fixing your service or changing your configuration settings so that role instances do not throw unhandled exceptions. Then start another update or upgrade operation. Until you start another update or upgrade operation, Windows Azure will continue trying to update your service to the new version or configuration you provided
7:02:47 PM - Deployment failed with a fatal error
```

When I check with intellitrace it tells me that there is a problem loading the Service Runtime.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.7.0.0
```

Currently I have the 1.7 DLL loaded with CopyLocal to False.   Does anyone have any idea why it would not load. I assume I don't need to set the to CopyLocal - True.

FYI the Web Platform Installer shows:

```
Windows Azure Libraries for .NET 1.7 Installed
Windows Azure Libraries for .NET 1.8 Installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following error message, it seems you are updating the cloud application with different version of SDK:

```
 Role instances recycled for a certain amount of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent role instances from running. 
 The most likely reason for this is that your code throws an unhandled exception. Please consider fixing your service or changing your configuration settings so that role instances do not throw unhandled exceptions. 
 Then start another update or upgrade operation. Until you start another update or upgrade operation, Windows Azure will continue trying to update your service to the new version or configuration you provided
```

So it is possible that your previous application is based on SDK 1.8 and the updated application is based on SDK version 1.7 and that's why you do see the error in intellitrace. Or it also shows that you application configuration changed a lot which needed NEW deployment rather then the UPDATE.

You can do the following:

- Ensure that both (previous and updated) application version are from same SDK. If SDK is same then update can go upto certain configuration setting but in some case a NEW deployment is needed and update will not work.
- If updated version is higher SDK, and the application configuration is changed based on some new feature in newer SDK, you would have to delete the deployment and deploy new.